# php and htaccess url rewriting issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to understand url rewriting methods by employing htaccess, on a lamp system.

I'm my website webmaster and I have full access on the system (ubuntu 12.04).

I successfully configured htaccess to remove www and index.php, so it seems to work fine.
Issues come when I try to rewrite a classical URL like the one in this example (thousand like this on the web):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ results.php?products=$1 [NC]
```

I would like to rewrite

```
mysite/results.php?products=string
```

to

```
mysite/string
```

so I think it is the right example.
Anyway, it doesn't work.
I tried few similar examples but I don't understand why it simply doesn't work.

My .htaccess:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Always remove www (with a hard redirect)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Try
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\d+)
    RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ results.php?products=$1 [R=301,QSA,L,NC]        

    </IfModule>
```

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]` - This rule of yours matches every URL that the server receives and the `[L]` means it should stop processing any rules after this. This is probably why your rewrite rule isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ results.php?products=$1 [L,QSA]
```